# Microsoft Teams status integration with Genesys Workspace Edition?

Tags: plugins, microsoft-teams, genesys

Since there exist plugin for Skype for Business that do much more than that.
How hard would that be to create similar plug-in for MS Team with only functionality would be taking the status from the Genesys and setting it up to the corresponding status in Ms Teams, so if someone is on the call everyone can see it on MS TEAMS and know he's not available.

Would someone with little experience in writing plug-ins could do it and where he could start? Maybe they already working on it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you to raise your [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new) here: